# How can I remove the explicit label from a song?

Tags: itunes

I bought a song from iTunes that is marked as explicit. However, the song is not actually explicit. When I try to edit the song's info in iTunes Music Library.xml, it simply reverts to the original information upon opening iTunes. Is there any way to remove the explicit label?

**Edit:** I would *prefer* to do this without any third party software, but it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: This label is not set by iTunes, it is set by the record company, in this case is Prospect Park.

With in music explicit lyrics are not necessarly fould words or drug refrences, they can be marked due to violence, or a whole album can be marked explicit if the concentration of songs contain these refrences.

Songs are also marked in this way if the tone is not suitable for minors, as this was a seperate sticker for recordes before partenal advisory and explicit lyrics. These record stickers have now all combined to just be a standard explicit lyrics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Remove rating for one song

The app [subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/) allows to edit a song's info manually. I've successfully tried version 0.14 in Lion.

[image]
[image]

### Remove (suppress) ratings for all songs

You can choose to not show explicit labels for all songs in the parental controls of iTunes: **iTunes Preferences -> Parental -> Show content ratings in library**

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, I actually want to remove the label entirely. Thanks though.

Comment: Having tried tweaking the xml file myself without success, I've found a solution using simple software. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Okay, if nothing better is posted, I'll accept.

Answer (score -4):

1. Go to Google and find "how to make MP3 files with iTunes"
2. Convert your song(s) to MP3, then that explicit label would be gone.
3. That's it, then you're done.